# R::dplyr combine tibbles on matching columns and replace NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tibbles `x` and `y` that I wish to combine into `out` such that NA columns in `x` are replaced by matching columns in `y`

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- tibble(name = c("hans", "dieter", "bohlen", "alf"), 
        location = c('NA','NA',1,2), 
        val1 = 1:4)
y <- tibble(name = c("hans", "dieter"), 
        location = c(2,2), 
        val1 = 1:2)

x
y
```

My desired output:

```
out <- tibble(name = c("hans", "dieter", "bohlen", "alf"), 
    location = c(2,2,1,2), 
    val1 = 1:4)
out
```

But using `left_join` or similar functions doesn't overwrite the NA values in X. I can't work out a solution from this question [Overwrite left_join dplyr to update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137949/overwrite-left-join-dplyr-to-update-data)

p.s. I can't seem to get the variables to print - any help on how to format the code to do that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- tibble(name = c("hans", "dieter", "bohlen", "alf"), 
            location = c(NA,NA,1,2), 
            val1 = 1:4)
y <- tibble(name = c("hans", "dieter"), 
            location = c(2,2), 
            val1 = 1:2)


out <- tibble(name = c("hans", "dieter", "bohlen", "alf"), 
              location = c(2,2,1,2), 
              val1 = 1:4)

rows_update(x = x, y = y, by = "name")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   name   location  val1
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <int>
#> 1 hans          2     1
#> 2 dieter        2     2
#> 3 bohlen        1     3
#> 4 alf           2     4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We could `coalesce` the 'location' columns after doing a `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   left_join(y %>%
          select(-val1), by = 'name') %>% 
    transmute(name, location = coalesce(as.numeric(location.x), location.y), val1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  name   location  val1
  <chr>     <dbl> <int>
1 hans          2     1
2 dieter        2     2
3 bohlen        1     3
4 alf           2     4
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick q - what did you write in the stackoverflow code to get the output tibble to print out in full?

Comment: @CocoNewton it is just a `left_join` and then  coalesce the .x, .y columns created from location so that if there is NA in .x, it gets replaced by the corresponding .y value